# How do I remove zero width characters from an excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file which contains lots of text, which I've just found out contains zero width characters, which don't show up normally.

I'm doing string comparisons, and they're causing problems.

Spent nearly an hour trying to find a way to remove them, but haven't found any way.

Linux terminal commands, and JavaScript replace functions I have found, but they don't apply to my case.

I tried using Replace function in Excel, but it says it didn't find anything to replace. However if I use Find only and paste in the zero width character, it DOES find them in the text. Replace doesn't work though.

Comment: Record a macro of pasting in the zero width character in the Find that you said works.  Then look at the code written for the macro and see what excel is calling that character.  Hopefully then, we can then write a custom macro.

Comment: Are these at the beginning,end, or in the middle of the field?  There is a trim() function which should remove them from the beginning and the end.

Comment: Is this about the occurrences of a specific zero-width character (which?) or about zero-width characters in general?

Comment: What are 'zero width characters'???? Do you mean the specific zero-width space character which is encoded in Unicode as U+200B zero width space (HTML: &#8203;)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a silly, but easy fix.

1. Select the entire column in Excel which contains data which has this
   character.
2. Copy the selection. Leave the selection ON. Don't unselect yet.
3. Paste the data in Notepad.
4. Use Notepad's Replace to remove all zero width characters.
5. Select all text in Notepad (CTRL + A) and copy it.
6. Paste it back in Excel, over the selection that was selected they
   before.

Easy ! Hope this helps others out :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this macro a try:

```
Sub deleteNothing()
    Dim rLook As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Len(r.Value) = 0 And wf.CountA(r) = 1 Then
            If rLook Is Nothing Then
                Set rLook = r
            Else
                Set rLook = Union(rLook, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If rLook Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rLook.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this, and I did need to go to VBA to fix this. The solution which worked for me was to open up the immediate window (press `Alt+F11` then `Ctrl + G`) and ran the following, which clears all the Zero Width Spaces (Unicode Character 8203) by replacing them with an empty string:

`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace What:=ChrW(8203), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart`

Just because you might want to check that's solved the problem, the code that I ran to check that it had a Zero Width Space in before I ran that was `Debug.Print instr(ActiveCell.Text, ChrW(8203))`. When I ran it before doing the `Replace` listed above, it returned `1`, and after running the `Replace`, it returned `0`, so that was a success.